# Uso della E commerciale

Tags: orthography, letters

Apparentemente in alcune lingue (e.g. il tedesco) è un errore grammaticale utilizzare la "e commerciale" (&) al posto della congiunzione coordinante *e*.

> **Q:** Posto che in italiano questo uso non è eccessivamente comune, è considerato un errore?

#### Cosa intendo per 'errore'

Una risposta dovrebbe presentare l'opinione di qualche "autorità" sulla lingua italiana, idealmente l'Accademia della Crusca o un ente similarmente sanzionato, ma in carenza di ciò sono accettabili anche manuali di stile o grammatiche ampiamente riconosciute come valide (e.g. il libro di Serianni).

Attenzione però: la fonte non deve semplicemente consigliare di evitare tale uso nella scrittura formale, ma esplicitamente dire che non è accettabile neppure in contesti informali.

Comment: Poi vedo se trovo una risposta argomentata alla domanda, ma quello su cui ho veramente da ridire è quando [si usa la & come una semplice lettera E (non congiunzione)](https://pignuoli.blogspot.com/2016/06/et-aut-e.html).

Comment: @DaG Ah quello è sicuramente un errore, nessuna obiezione da parte mia :).

Comment: Curiosamente, ho visto parecchie volte  (in mostre temporanee o musei) libri in italiano stampati nel periodo rinascimentale che usano il simbolo "&" invece della congiunzione "e".

Comment: @Charo Difatti era l'uso normale (e per capirne la ragione basta provare a scrivere a mano, la & è fatta apposta per consistere d'un solo tratto). A un certo punto è caduta in disuso e vorrei sapere se siamo giunti al considerarla addirittura un errore

Comment: Non mi è chiara la tua domanda. Il simbolo & viene usato in alcuni contesti di natura commerciale tipo la ditta Rossi & Bianchi, ma non certo in frasi come “io & mio papà siamo andati al cinema”. Quindi la tua domanda è se l’utilizzo del simbolo & è accettabile in quest’ultima frase?

Comment: @Gio Esatto (apparentemente in tedesco non lo è, cosa che mi ha sorpreso non poco)

Comment: Nei nomi commerciali è diffuso e accettato. Mi sembra invece che in altri contesti sia così raro che non è “neppure sbagliato”: non so se qualcuno si è pronunciato sulla correttezza di qualcosa che, a parte qualche caso isolato, non si usa fare...

Comment: @DaG Sembra essere parecchio usato anche nei titoli dei libri (tra cui alcuni di grammatica :))

Comment: @DenisNardin: Potresti fare qualche esempio?

Comment: @Charo Per esempio [questo](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/referenza-bibliografica/novit-bibliografiche/linguaggio-comunicazione-introduzione-linguistica)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Interessante, non ci avevo pensato. Personalmente, sospetto che in certi casi sia più una scelta di design o di marketing, che poi rimane “attaccata” al libro. Per esempio, per il libro che citi, [sul sito dell'editore](https://www.zanichelli.it/ricerca/prodotti/linguaggio-e-comunicazione) si vede per esempio anche che la “C” di “comunicazione” è maiuscola, contro le usuali norme dei titoli in italiano, quasi come se volessero fare del titolo del libro una specie di marchio.

Answer (score 1):

Non so se sia una fonte attendibile, comunque questo estratto da sapere.it riguardo l’uso del simbolo & nota che:

> In italiano si riconosce come “e commerciale”: in realtà il suo nome è "ampersand" ed è il simbolo della congiunzione coordinativa "e", l’"and" inglese.
>
> In passato l’ampersand veniva collocata al termine dell’alfabeto latino, come se fosse una lettera a sé stante; prese il nome di ampersand nell’Ottocento in Gran Bretagna e pur occupando l'ultimo posto anche nell'alfabeto inglese, dopo la zed (zeta).
>
> ***Oggi si usa di solito nei nomi di imprese commerciali, non più nel linguaggio corrente.***

Comment: Non so se sia attendibile o meno, ma è curioso dire che “in realtà il suo nome è ‘ampersand’”, visto che questo è il nome inglese, entrato in uso alla fine del Settecento, quando invece in italiano [si smetteva di usare questo simbolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/et/).

Comment: Questo articolo mi sembra un po' bizzarro: infatti il nome *ampersand* deriva proprio dal fatto che fosse l'ultima lettera dell'alfabeto inglese. Ma non riesco a capire: è considerato un uso corretto o no? (Avevo già scritto nella domanda che non è un uso frequente)

Comment: @DenisNardin - corretto? Cioè se la frase “io & mia nonna andiamo al mercato” è corretta?